# Android zbluetooth apps compilation and testing in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth

I am building Android Apps and I am facing problems in compiling and testing Android apps supporting bluetooth.

Is there a way out.. Is there any other emulator which can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator has no support for Bluetooth and USB, so you can you cannot use them, at least at this moment. Maybe in future versions they will include support for Bluetooth too.

[On this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) page you'll find a complete list of what is not supported related to networking.